# Peak voltage rating means voltage drop?

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio, ldr

[This LDR](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Ceramic-VT43N1-LDR-Photocell-Resistor-400V-400mW-NEW-/330769520089?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4d036655d9) is said to have Peak voltage rating of 400V in the description. Does this equal the voltage drop, meaning that I need to supply at least 400V or is it the maximum voltage value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

400 V seems a stretch for that.  The LDR is claimed to be able to dissipate 400 mW, which is plausible enough.  To dissipate 400 mW at 400 V would mean the resistance is 400 kΩ, which is also possible for a CdS cell like the one shown.  However, whether it can really withstand 400 V without breakdown is another matter.

Since the price seems high and there doesn't seem to be a datasheet, I'd move along and forget about this one.

What the 400 V rating is saying (whether it is correct or not is another issue), is that this is the maximum voltage you can ever put accross this device.  That does not mean you have to, and in any normal light sensing circuit you would put much much less than that accross it.  This device will operate fine (vary it's resistance as a function of light) at any voltage down to 0.  You can use this in a 3 V battery-operated circuit, for example.

Answer (score 2):

That's an absolute maximum. It will work fine with low voltages.